# Write each test result to excel file by Python, pytest

Tags: python, excel, pytest, data-driven

I would like to write each test result to excel file. I am using data-driven by pytest to execute all rows in worksheet. But I don't know how to write the test result to each row. Had someone similar experience? May you give advice? Thanks very much!

file 1: read_excel.py

```
class ReadExcel:

    def __init__(self, file_name, sheet_name):
        self.file_name = os.path.join(rc.DATA_PATH, file_name)
        self.sheet_name = sheet_name

    def open(self):
        self.wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.file_name)
        self.sh = self.wb[self.sheet_name]

    def close(self):
        self.wb.close()

    def read_data(self):
        """read rows"""
        self.open()
        rows = list(self.sh.rows)
        titles = []
        for t in rows[0]:
            title = t.value
            titles.append(title)
        cases = []
        for row in rows[1:]:
            case = []
            for r in row:
                case.append(r.value)
            cases.append(dict(zip(titles, case)))
        self.close()
        return cases

    def write_data(self, row, column, msg):
        self.open()
        self.sh.cell(row=row, column=column, value=msg)
        self.wb.save(self.file_name)
        self.close()
```

file2: test_sample.py

```
class TestSample:

    sheet = ReadExcel('test_data.xlsx', 'test_data')
    rows = sheet.read_data()
    test_result = []
    i=2 

    @pytest.fixture(scope='function', params=rows)
    def _test_data(self, request):
        return request.param

    def test_write_result(self, drivers, _test_data):
        # get all required test data from excel
        test_case_no = _test_data['TEST CASE_NO.']
        # I want to write each test result to the excel file, but below code does not work, it only write the second row
        self.sheet.write_data(self.i, 2, "pass")
        self.i = self.i + 1
```

test_data.xlsx

|TEST CASE_NO.|TEST RESULT|

|     1       |           |

|     2       |           |

|     3       |           |

Answer (score 0):

**pytest-csv** works for me and love it

Firstly install:

```py
pip install pytest-csv
```

then instead of `pytest....` type `py.test --csv tests.csv` in command line (terminal)

Maybe not exactly **XLSX**, but **CSV** also is fine

Documentation: https://github.com/nicoulaj/pytest-csv